# Jekyll ruby questions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jekyll

what is the solution for jekyll erros see: http://pastebin.com/7Y6zVn5L  and http://pastebin.com/MuRK0EQr  no problems with Hyde...

```
C:\Users\DEV\Desktop\_blog>jekyll serve -w
Configuration file: C:/Users/DEV/Desktop/_blog/_config.yml
        Source: C:/Users/DEV/Desktop/_blog
   Destination: C:/Users/DEV/Desktop/_blog/_site
  Generating...
jekyll 2.4.0 | Error:  undefined method `in_source_dir' for #<Jekyll::Site:0x00000003d74828>

C:\Users\DEV\Desktop\_blog>
Microsoft Windows [versie 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation. Alle rechten voorbehouden.

C:\Users\DEV>gem list -- local

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bigdecimal (1.2.0)
blankslate (2.1.2.4)
bundler (1.7.7)
celluloid (0.16.0)
classifier-reborn (2.0.2)
coffee-script (2.3.0)
coffee-script-source (1.8.0)
colorator (0.1)
execjs (2.2.2)
fast-stemmer (1.0.2)
ffi (1.9.6 x64-mingw32)
hitimes (1.2.2)
io-console (0.4.2)
jekyll (2.4.0)
jekyll-coffeescript (1.0.1)
jekyll-gist (1.1.0)
jekyll-paginate (1.1.0)
jekyll-sass-converter (1.2.1)
jekyll-sitemap (0.6.2)
jekyll-watch (1.1.2)
json (1.7.7)
kramdown (1.5.0)
liquid (2.6.1)
listen (2.8.2, 2.7.11)
mercenary (0.3.5, 0.3.4)
minitest (4.3.2)
octopress (3.0.0.rc.16, 3.0.0.rc.15)
octopress-deploy (1.0.0)
octopress-docs (0.0.9)
octopress-escape-code (1.0.2)
octopress-hooks (2.2.1)
parslet (1.5.0)
posix-spawn (0.3.9)
psych (2.0.0)
pygments.rb (0.6.0)
rake (0.9.6)
rb-fsevent (0.9.4)
rb-inotify (0.9.5)
rdoc (4.0.0)
redcarpet (3.2.1, 3.2.0)
rouge (1.7.4)
safe_yaml (1.0.4)
sass (3.4.9, 3.4.7)
test-unit (2.0.0.0)
timers (4.0.1)
titlecase (0.1.1)
toml (0.1.2)
yajl-ruby (1.1.0)

C:\Users\DEV>
```

Comment: http://mmistakes.github.io/minimal-mistakes/theme-setup/

Comment: Have you tried with recent versions of jekyll? https://github.com/mmistakes/hpstr-jekyll-theme/issues/55